# Need to check if these logic answers are correct =)

Tags: logic, solution-verification, predicate-logic

Are my answers true or wrong or not even wrong?

Exercises says translate the following english sentences into symbolic sentences with quantifiers quantifiers the universe for each is given in parentheses (there's no problem if i just wrote an equivalent statement and not the exact model in which the statement is written see the comments)

> **(a)** Not all precious stones are beautiful. (All Stones)

Old answer:
$$\text{$(\exists x)$$($$x$ is precious $\wedge$ $x$ isn't beautiful$)$}$$
New answer:
$$\neg(\forall x)(\text{$x$ is precious $\implies$ $x$ is beautiful})$$

> **(b)** All precious stones are not beautiful. (All Stones)

Old answer:
$$\text{$(\forall x)$$($$x$ is precious $\implies$ $x$ isn't beautiful$)$}$$
New answer:
$$\text{$(\forall x)$$($$x$ is precious $\implies$ $\neg$($x$ is beautiful)$)$}$$

> **(c)** Some isosceles triangle is a right triangle. (All Triangles)

Old answer = New answer:
$$\text{$(\exists x)$$($$x$ is isosceles $\wedge$ $x$ is right$)$}$$

> **(d)** No right triangle is isosceles. (All Triangles)

Old answer:
$$\text{$(\forall x)$$($$x$ is right $\implies$ $x$ isn't isosceles$)$}$$
New answer:
$$\text{$\neg(\exists x)$$($$x$ is right $\wedge$ $x$ is isosceles$)$}$$

> **(e)** All people are honest or no one is honest (All People)

Old answer:
$$\text{$(\forall x)$$($$x$ is honest$)$ $\vee$ $(\forall y)(y$ isn't honest$)$}$$
New answer:
$$\text{$(\forall x)$$($$x$ is honest$)$ $\vee$ $\neg(\exists y)(y$ is honest$)$}$$

> **(f)** Some people are honest and some people are not honest. (All People)

Old answer:
$$\text{$(\exists x)(x$ is honest$)$ $\wedge$ $(\exists x)(x$ isn't honest$)$}$$
New answer:
$$\text{$(\exists x)(x$ is honest$)$ $\wedge$ $(\exists x)(\neg(x$ is honest$))$}$$

> **(g)** Every nonzero real number is positive or negative. (Real Numbers)

Old answer = New answer:
$$\text{$(\forall x)(x\neq0$ $\implies$ $x\gt0$ $\vee$ $x\lt0$$)$}$$

> **(h)** Every integer is greater than -4 or less than 6. (Real Numbers)

Old answer = New answer:
$$\text{$(\forall x)(x\in\mathbb{Z}$ $\implies$ $x\gt-4$ $\vee$ $x\lt6$$)$}$$

> **(i)** Every integer is greater than some integer. (Integers)

Old answer = New answer:
$$\text{$(\forall x)(\exists y)($$x\gt y$$)$}$$

> **(j)** No integer is greater than every other integer. (Integers)

Old answer:
$$\text{$(\forall x)(\exists y)(x\le y)$}$$
New answer:
$$\text{$\neg(\exists x)(\forall y)(x\gt y)$}$$

> **(k)** Between any integer and any larger integer, there is a real number. (Real Numbers)

Old answer = New answer:
$$\text{$(\forall x)$$(\forall y)$$[$$x\in\mathbb{Z}$ $\wedge$ $y\in\mathbb{Z}$ $\wedge$ $x\gt y$ $\implies$ $(\exists z)$$($$x\gt z\gt y$$)$$]$}$$

> **(l)** There is a smallest positive integer. (Real Numbers)

Old answer = New answer:
$$\text{$(\exists x)$$(\forall y)$$($$x\gt0$ $\wedge$ $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ $\wedge$ $y\in\mathbb{Z}$ $\wedge$ $y\gt0$ $\wedge$ $x\ne y$ $\implies$ $x\lt y$ $)$}$$

> **(m)** No one loves everybody. (All People)

Old answer:
$$\text{$(\forall x)$$(\exists y)$$($$x$ doesn't love $y$$)$}$$
New answer:
$$\text{$\neg(\exists x)$$(\forall y)$$($$x$ loves $y$$)$}$$

> **(n)** Everybody loves someone. (All People)

Old answer = New answer:
$$\text{$(\forall x)$$(\exists y)$$($$x$ loves $y$$)$}$$

> **(o)** For every positive real number $x$ there is a unique real number $y$ such that $2^y=x$. (Real Numbers)

Old answer = New answer:
$$\text{$(\forall x)$$(\exists!y)$$($$x=2^y$$)$}$$

Also side question do you think that with lots of efforts with hours of practice like these exercises i can get better and with 400000 hours of practice i can be the best in a domain? Thnx =) =) And sorry for my bad english :/

Comment: A few remarks. Your english is fine. I only read the first three and the last one, your ideas are right. However I'd expect you to replace the sentences by predicates symbols, for instance in the first one it would be $\exists x(P(x)\land \neg B(x))$ where $P$ and $B$ are unary predicates which mean what you expect them to mean. So for starters provide a key (i.e. abbreviate $x\text{ is whatever}$ and replace the sentence by the abbreviation).

Comment: Finally, about the first one, it is equivalent to $\neg \forall x(P(x)\to B(x))$, but I claim that this version is correct and yours isn't. The natural modelling of the given sentence is what I wrote. What you wrote is equivalent, but it is not how one would model that sentence.

Comment: first comment: But they are equivalent @GitGud , so there's not much problem, right? No? second comment: ($\neg \forall x(P(x)\to B(x))$ is how i wrote it first but then i used the rules in our course to find one equivalent to it like this $$\neg \forall x(P(x)\to B(x))\iff \exists x\neg(P(x)\to B(x))\iff\exists x(P(x)\wedge\neg B(x))$$

Comment: Also I have doubts about validity of **(l)** can you please check it?

Comment: Well, it really depends on what your lecturer wants. The point of writing in predicate calculus is to be able to employ logical rules and strip away the sentences of their meaning. Doing what you did kind of defeats that purpose. Not only that, but it's not written in your formal language and writing it in the formal language (i.e. just using quantifiers, predicate symbols, connectives, ...) is probably what the problem intends. What you wrote for $\textbf{(l)}$ is right.

Comment: Regarding the other matter, yes, they are equivalent, but that doesn't mean they are the same sentence. Think about $2<3$ and $5<6$. They are equivalent, but they do not say the same, do they? Anyway, I suspect most people would say that what you suggest for the first one is correct. I wouldn't.

Comment: Okay thanks you gave me new insights I will rewrite all the answers so that they fit your requirements.

Comment: I forgot to mention, about the last one, you might not be allowed to use $\exists !$, so you might have to rewrite it.

Comment: @GitGud why? because we learned about the unique existential quantifier

Comment: Many times $\exists !$ isn't part of the language and $\exists !xP(x)$ is written just as a written abbreviation of $\exists x(P(x)\land \forall y(P(y)\to x=y))$. If you're allowed to use it, you're allowed to use it and what you did is correct. If you're not allowed to use it, you're not allowed to use it and what you did isn't correct. From what you say, it seems you're allowed to use it.

Comment: I'm allowed to use it, I updated my question with the new answers.$